# $FeatureNotEnabledException using App Engine bundled service Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, migration, datastore

Migrating my GAE service from Java 8 to Java 11, I'm using App Engine bundled service.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/support-for-app-engine-services-in-second-generation-runtimes

API document shows there are datastore APIs,

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/reference/services/bundled

But when I deploy my service on Java 11 runtime, I got $FeatureNotEnabledException

> javax.servlet.ServletException: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: datastore_v3.RunQuery

There's a blog post saying it's back,

https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Updates-from-the-Google-App-Engine-team-Fall-2021/td-p/174941

But I'm not sure I can use "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query" like

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    Key         key         = KeyFactory.createKey("Memobook", user.getEmail());
    Query       query       = new Query("Memo", key);
    datastore.prepare(query);
```

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: It's ridiculous that Google has set a deadline for GAE Java 8 migration but there's still no solution for this issue...

Answer (score 0):

Adding true
in the appengine-web.xml would enable the APIs.
Did you try that?

See doc in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/services/access

Comment: This doesn't help.  It breaks the build with:  `com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Unrecognized element <app-engine-apis>`

Answer (score 0):

support was added in recent Cloud SDK CLI versions and recent GAE Maven and Gradle plugins.

Make sure you use latest versions of all these tools and that you do not pin an old Cloud SDK version in the pom.xml or Gradle build file.
With latest versions, you should be fine.

For ex: Cloud SDK CLI version: 460.0.0 or later
Maven GAE plugin: 2.5.1 or later
Gradle GAE Plugin: 2.5.0 or later

But:
So maybe the endpoint plugin is pointing to an old tooling version:

See https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/blob/master/endpoints-framework-tools/build.gradle

https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/blob/44933a4d5d38b7bf6a11ee0c139a120563ef9d6b/gradle.properties#L12 is way too old!

This repo has been archived, not sure why, but definitely the issue.